# Django Elasticbeanstalk Application returns 404 during autoscale

Tags: django, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django application running on elastic beanstalk. The application deploys and works fine when I deploy from the command line. 
However, during an autoscale, healthcheck on the new instance created always return 404 from the access_logs.

> "GET /health/ HTTP/1.1" 404 221 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"

Interestingly, the application eventually loads after about 20 minutes.
See my wsgi.conf file below.
Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
<VirtualHost *:80>

Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/staticfiles/
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/staticfiles/>
Require all granted
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/myapp/wsgi.py


<Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
Require all granted
</Directory>

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE, PATCH"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, Accept, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token, Authorization"
WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=3 threads=20 display-name=%{GROUP} \
  python-path=/opt/python/current/app:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7/site-packages user=wsgi group=wsgi \
  home=/opt/python/current/app
WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule !/api/v1.0/church/health/ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

Comment: you can access the logs of your instance and see where it get stuck. Could you provide that?

Comment: From the logs, there's no indication that it got stuck

Answer (score 0):

I have the check of the health just for production and the url I use is the `/login`

Have a look in `configuration>health` in your EBT dashboard.

I have the suspect that your url `/health` is not managed by django.